# SQL syntax error with AS

Tags: sql, postgresql, debugging, syntax

I am not that familiar with SQL, and am getting a syntax error for this query. I suspect that I may be using the 'AS' keyword incorrectly. Could anyone check my syntax here? I also tried using [] in place of single quotes.
Thanks!

```
SELECT m.dname, COUNT(*) AS 'Total Students', AVG(s.age) AS 'Average Age', 
AVG(s.gpa) AS 'Average GPA'
FROM student s JOIN major m
ON s.sid = m.sid
GROUP BY m.dname
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

EDIT ****

The error I'm getting:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "'Total Students'" LINE 1: SELECT m.dname, COUNT(*) AS 'Total Students', AVG(s.age) AS... ^
```

Using PostgreSQL database

Comment: you could share the error message

Comment: Edit your question and (1) provide the actual error and (2) tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In postgres, for column aliases containing whitespace, use double quotes, not single quotes:

```
SELECT m.dname, COUNT(*) AS "Total Students", AVG(s.age) AS "Average Age", 
AVG(s.gpa) AS "Average GPA"
FROM student s JOIN major m
ON s.sid = m.sid
GROUP BY m.dname
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

-- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT-LIST

Comment: this assumes mysql, which (per the recent tag edit) is wrong

Comment: That's not specific to Postgres. Using double quotes for identifiers is specified in the SQL standard.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need of quotes when using AS

Try this

```
SELECT m.dname, COUNT(*) AS Total_Students, AVG(s.age) AS Average_Age, 
AVG(s.gpa) AS Average_GPA
FROM student s JOIN major m
ON s.sid = m.sid
GROUP BY m.dname
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Comment: Sure, but you've removed the whitespace from the table alias. Your solution won't work if the OP wants to preserve the whitespace.